# Deployment Slot for Azure Scheduler and Azure logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-apps, azure-scheduler

I am trying to build a logic flow which will be triggered by the scheduler . The scheduler will send a message to the service queue. And the Service queue will be by trigger point for the logic app.

Now the issue is that , I want to have a version running on different slots (deployment slots) or (Staging/Production) . I tried hard to find it on AZURE PORTAL ,but was not able to locate the deployment slots for AZURE SCHEDULER / AZURE LOGIC APP.

Can someone guide me how can i create the Slots/Staging for SCHEDULER / LOGIC APPS.

I was able to create the slots for Azure functions as the settings in the Azure functions have the option to create the slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone guide me how can i create the Slots/Staging for SCHEDULER / LOGIC APPS.

Currently, there is no **Deployment slots** option for Azure logic app. Here is a [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/11127249-multiple-slots), you can vote for it and track status.

Comment: And what about the scheduler ? It's the same as logic app ?

Comment: Yes, Azure Scheduler do not have Deployment slots option too at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If the Azure Scheduler is just for dropping a message into a Service Bus Queue, you could use an Azure Function with a [Timer Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) that does this. With Functions you have deployment slots.

Logic Apps have version history, and you can [promote an old version](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/logicappsupdate/2017/02/27/release-update-2017-03-03/). If you want both versions running side-by-side, you might need two different logic apps. Each of them listening to a different service bus queue, or same topic with different subscriptions.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Recurrence` trigger to execute Logic App on a schedule, there's no need to use Scheduler to trigger a Logic App.